# Strange behaviour about rendered file's size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In controller, I have something like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.ini do
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=somefile.ini"
    render ini: SomeClass.make_ini(data)
  end
end
```

`SomeClass.make_ini(data)` renders the correct ini file (1.5MB) for API users. There is a task from our clients to add `Content-Length` header. The reason doesn't matter.

When I try:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.ini do
    file = SomeClass.make_ini(data)
    response.headers['Content-Length'] = file.size.to_s
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=somefile.ini"
    render ini: file
  end
end
```

`file.size.to_s` brings `1301761`. And after setting `Content-Length`, the rendered file is 1.2MB. And content is cut.

I would be grateful if someone could tell the reason.

Comment: If you use curl, do you still get the same truncated result? Is the `Content-Length` in the header via curl also as you expect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you have characters in the file that needs more than 1 byte to be stored. You should use the method bytesize instead of size.

You can find an example of the problem you have using size instead of bytesize [here](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.3.0/method/String/i/bytesize.html). size returns the number of characters, but you want the number of bytes, returned by the method bytesize.

UTF-8 uses between 1 and 4 bytes for storing the characters.

Comment: But `size` is a method on a File object and not a String object, so it should not be returning the number of characters, but rather the number of bytes, no? What *is* SomeClass.make_ini returning?

Comment: I would say it is returning a string that is rendered with .ini format. So file variable it's not a file, but a string with the content of the file .ini returned. I would say you need to send a string to the render function, not a file.

Comment: @ArtyomKalmykov Please tell us what is the class of the object returned by SomeClass.make_ini?

Comment: Base on the size that was returned and how bytesize resolved his issue... I think it is clear it is a string.

Comment: Yes, this is string.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `SomeClass.make_ini` returns an instance of Ruby's `File` class, its `size` method should return the number of bytes, not the number of characters:

```
 :001 > File.write('japanese.txt', "ルビー")
 => 9
 :002 > file = File.new('japanese.txt')
 => #<File:japanese.txt>
 :003 > file.size
 => 9
```

Could it be that you have to set the content type in the response header?